# MongoDB setup with node.js: Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, backbone.js, mongoose

I am getting the error:
"failed to connect to [localhost:27017]" while trying to follow [this tutorial](http://kroltech.com/2013/12/boilerplate-web-app-using-backbone-js-expressjs-node-js-mongodb/).

I've been attempting to do several other node.js tutorials with mongoDB over the past few days, and each one runs into similar problems.
The other solutions I've found surrounding this all involve people not having the server running when trying to connect. I have mongod running in a terminal window, can view the info in the browser at localhost, and have added and viewed records to the database through the mongo shell. All of that appears to be working. The breakage seems to be in connecting any of the node.js projects to the database, but being pretty new to this, I am not even sure where to begin troubleshooting.

RESOLVED: very stupid mistake on my part. The [file](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native#introduction) suggested by Neil below (view here was instrumental in helping me to troubleshoot and find the problem, though.

needed to change the line

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/MyApp');
```

to

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test');
```

in the server.js file.

Additional note: for reasons I don't quite understand, specifying the address as 127.0.0.1: works, but localhost: does not.

Comment: the fact that it only works with 127.0.0.1 may be related with having bind_ip=127.0.0.1 in /etc/mongo.conf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just for my curiousity, can you do

```
npm install mongoose
```

and also post the output from

```
ps -ef | grep mongod
```

All on the the machine you are running node from. That would go a long way towards the rest of an answer.

Also follow the simple sample code right after [here](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native#introduction), substitute the database name and a collection name and run that on node

```
node sample.js
```

Edit your post to include more information. It will all help.

Comment: Did `npm install mongoose`, which ran without errors, but did not have an effect on the problem. Output from grep command:    `euterpe:benm me$ ps -ef | grep mongod
  502 16818 13001   0 12:26AM ttys002    0:11.65 /usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/2.4.9/mongod --rest --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf
  502 17373  6467   0 12:40AM ttys003    0:00.00 grep mongod`

Comment: try running something very simple in node connecting to mongo as suggested. Edit your question with the additional information you find. As it stands it's just a block of text. People will ignore you and vote the question down.

Comment: Thanks - I have been experimenting with the sample file you linked to to try and get a better handle on the problem. Will update when I have more of a clue and can explain better. So far it is helping.

Comment: solved. It was a pretty dumb mistake, but the file you linked to helped increase my understanding enough to find it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

just start mongo server 
or run on mongo.exe and type

> mongod

then

> mongo